# How to access Terraform Lambda Variables in Ruby Lambda Function?

Tags: ruby, lambda, aws-sdk, terraform

I have terraform code which creates a Lambda function. I then have some ruby code that is the lambda function. I can not figure out, or find any information in how to actually use the variables which are being passed in from the terraform into the lambda. I ultimately just need to know how to use the terraform variables in the ruby lambda function

I have found examples in python and JS. There is little similarities.

Here is my terraform code

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "send_sns_lambda" {
  filename         = "statuslambda.zip"
  function_name    = "status-page-send-sns"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.status_lambdas.output_base64sha256}"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.status_lambda.arn}"
  handler          = "statusLambda.send_sns"

  runtime = "ruby2.5"

  vpc_config = {
    subnet_ids         = ["subnet-xxxx", "subnet-xxxxx"]
    security_group_ids = ["sg-xxxxxx"]
  }

  environment = {
    variables = {
      status = "Major Outage"
    }
  }
}
```

And my Lambda function

```rb
def send_sns(event:,context:)
  sns = Aws::SNS::Resource.new(region: 'us-xxx-xxx')
  topic = sns.topic('arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx')


  topic.publish({
    message: '#{status}'
  })

end
```

The idea is that the `status` variable in terraform gets passed into the status variable in the ruby code

Here is the python example I have found

```py
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return "{} from Lambda!".format(os.environ['greeting'])
```

Comment: So your question is "how to access environment variables in Ruby"? That would be `ENV['status']`.

Comment: Oh man. Thanks that worked!

Comment: filed it as an answer, so that this can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is "how to access environment variables in Ruby"? That would be `ENV['status']`.